# Crear consulta a travez de filtros y transformaciones en Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

Hola tengo la siguiente función index en un controlador la cual me devuelve, utilizando un transformador o transformacion, todos los datos correctamente, el problema es que necesito traer solamente los registros a travez de uno o varios filtros (ya sea nombre, apellido, celular, domicilio, dni, etc)

esto es lo que tengo en el index del controlador y funciona

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
         if (request()->user()->hasRole('admin')) 
            {
                $contracts = Contract::with('affiliates')
                                ->get();
            } 
            else 
            {
                $contracts = Contract::with('affiliates')
                            ->whereBranchId(request()->user()->branch_id)
                            ->get();
            }
         return fractal()->collection($contracts)->transformWith(new IndexTransformer)->toArray()['data'];

    }
```

esto es lo tengo en el transformador:

```
        public function transform(Contract $contract)
        {
            return [
                'id' => $contract->id,
                'number' => $contract->full_number,
                'holder_last_name' => $contract->holder->last_name,
                'holder_first_name' => $contract->holder->first_name,
                'domicile' => $contract->domicile,
                'phone' => $contract->phone,
                'cellphone' => $contract->cellphone,
                'branch' => $contract->branch->name,
                'current_fee' => $contract->current_fee,
            ];
        }
```

estos son los scope que se encuentran en el modelo para realiza la busqueda filtrada:

```
        public function scopeName($query, $name)
        {
            if($name)
            {
                return $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%$name%");
            }
        }
        public function scopelastname($query, $lastname)
        {
            if($lastname)
            {
                return $query->where('last_name', 'LIKE', "%$lastname%");
            }
        }
        public function scopedni($query, $dni)
        {
            if($dni)
            {
                return $query->where('document_number', 'LIKE', "%$dni%");
            }
        }
        public function scopecellphone($query, $cellphone)
        {
            if($cellphone)
            {
                return $query->where('cellphone', 'LIKE', "%$cellphone%");
            }
        }
        public function scopedomicile($query, $domicile)
        {
            if($domicile)
            {
                return $query->where('domicile', 'LIKE', "%$domicile%");
            }
        }
        public function scopecdcontract($query, $cdcontract)
        {
            if($cdcontract)
            {
                return $query->where('id', 'LIKE', "%$cdcontract%");
            }
        }
```

Estos son los cambios que le hice al index para tratar de devolver los datos a travez de filtros pero no funciona:

```
        public function index(Request $request)
        {

            $name       = $request->get('first_name');
            $lastname   = $request->get('last_name');
            $dni        = $request->get('document_number');
            $cellphone  = $request->get('cellphone');
            $domicile   = $request->get('domicile');
            $cdcontract = $request->get('id');


            if (request()->user()->hasRole('admin')) 
            {
                $contracts = Contract::with('affiliates')
                        ->first_name($name)
                        ->last_name($lastname)
                        ->document_number($dni)
                        ->cellphone($cellphone)
                        ->domicile($domicile)
                        ->id($cdcontract)
                                ->get();
            } 
            else 
            {
                $contracts = Contract::with('affiliates')
                            ->whereBranchId(request()->user()->branch_id)
                            ->get();
            }
            return fractal()->collection($contracts)->transformWith(new IndexTransformer)->toArray()['data'];
```

Comment: Deberias de publicar el codigo, No imagenes.

Comment: ok ya lo paso al codigo, lo que pasa es que son varios archivos

Comment: Que tiene que ver vue en esta pregunta?

Comment: perdon, es que tengo la parte del front end en vue

Comment: Cuando dices "no funciona", que es lo que no funciona? Prueba esta sintaxis en los where de los scopes `"%".$name."%"` o `"%{$name}%"`, en vez de `"%$name%"`.

Comment: lo que no funciona es la funcion index al agregarle los campos de busqueda que le llegan por el request

Comment: ok, entiendo que el resultado esperado es una colección "filtrada", pero cual es el resultado que obtienes para decir que no funciona? te da un error, te devuelve los datos sin filtrar, devuelve una colección vacía?

Comment: esto es lo que me sale: createError.js?2d83:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:77)

Comment: tendrías que mirar los logs de laravel, están en el archivo `/storage/logs/laravel.log` de tu proyecto